# How to Access Magento2.3 Instance with PWA

Tags: magento2.3, pwa-studio

I have successfully completed the steps to install the PWA in Our Magento 2.3 version with PWA Studio.

[Here is the completion screen.](https://magento2.oscprofessionals.in/PWA-installation.jpg)
[image]

Even after PWAserver Ready the url not working (Assuming its a Venia local server URL and not be accessible through the Internet)

Can anyone help me out, How to access our magento instance with PWA?

Thanks in advance for your time and Support.

Thanks!!

Comment: have you got anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit **pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/.env**

Add following bottom of this file:

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://magento-pwa.com/"
```

Here **magento-pwa.com** is your local instance URL and should be accessible.

After that

```
yarn run build
yarn run watch:venia
```